# JMeter: Passing Results of SQL Query as a Variable

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I've been reading through the forums, the [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) guide, and BlazeMeter's [*The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter*](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) and [*Using JDBC Sampler In JMeter*](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter), but I'm still kind of lost.

I need to issue a query to extract an Obj ID value from a table and pass that value into an HTTP READ Request. I've done the following setup:

**JDBC Request**
    Variable Name: Pool-1
    Query Type: Select Statement
    Query: `select distinct ObjId from dbo.CommonRuleSet where Name like '%ABC%';`
    Param. values:
    Param. types:
    Variable names: abcObjId
    Result variable name: `abcCommonRule = vars.getObject("resultObject").get(0).get("ObjId");`
    Query Timeout (s): 5000
    Handle Result Set: Store as Object

When executed results in:
`ObjId`
`1136682203`

**I'm trying to figure out how to pass in this ObjId value as a variable to append the URL**.

**HTTP REQUEST**
database:port/applicationServer/../../crud/CommonRuleSet/**????**

I've tried appending using:

1. the Variable names value: ${abcObjId}
2. the Result Variable Name: ${abcResult}

Each time, JMeter is not translating the variable resulting in  a parser error. 
(e.g., `http://database:port/.../.../.../crud/CommonRuleSet/`**`${abcResult}`**)

I'm just not understanding how to take the results of my successful query and pass it as a variable to an HTTP Request. Any insight/enlightenment is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The solution was:
//database:port/.../.../.../crud/CommonRuleSet/${abcObjId**_1**}).

I guess I didn't go through enough BlazeMeter pages before posting my question. I found the solution on [*Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter*](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter).

The section explaining the difference and usage between Variable Names and *Result Variable Name* made all the difference. I now understand the *Result Variable Name* is an ArrayList of HashMaps, which I don't need in this scenario. 
So I changed the *Result Variable Name* field
 **from:** `abcCommonRule = vars.getObject("resultObject").get(0).get("ObjId");` 
 **to:** result,

Next, since I want to directly access the *Variable Name* 'abcObjId', I modified the variable that appends my URL
**from:** ${abcObjId}
**to:** ${abcObjId_1}. 
 I was so close... so close....
Thanks to dmitri-t and the folks at Blazemeter.